# I am Confused with the ERROR_PROTECTION_VIOLATION

Tags: linux, tcp

I use TCP function "recv" to receive data. Then use GetLastError() to display the error id. It is 115. In windows error.h it is #define ERROR_PROTECTION_VIOLATION  115 /* Bad user virtual address */. Could you give me any advice?
PS: this program is running under the linux.But I think the error code in linux && windows must be the same as TCP error.

Comment: `GetLastError()` is not a standard Linux function, as far as I know; if `recv()` gets an error, the code is put in the variable `errno`. And there's no reason to assume that error codes are the same on Linux and Windows. They might not even be the same on different flavors of Unix.

Comment: I use a macro to use it in different platform.int GetLastError()
{
#if PLATFORM == PLATFORM_WIN32
    return ::GetLastError();
#elif PLATFORM_IS_LINUX
    return errno;
#endif
}

Comment: You actually should have shown relevant part of your source code in the question, not in comments. You should be able to edit your own question and improve it. The title is grossly wrong.

Comment: `recv` is *not* a *TCP* function, it is provided by the socket API (which you could also use for UDP) which on Linux is implemented thru syscalls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error codes are certainly operating system specific (so your belief that it should be the same on Windows and Linux is wrong). On Linux, you should read the [errno(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/errno.3.html) man page (which you can obtain with the `man 3 errno` command after installing `manpages` and `manpages-dev` packages).

<sup>[TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) don't define error codes, AFAIK. It defines a protocol.</sup>

A portable way to use `errno` is to use symbolic names like `EPERM` and to report the error to the user with  `strerror(errno)` or `perror`. See [strerror(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strerror.3.html) and [perror(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/perror.3.html). The actual error numbers are system specific (i.e. probably not the same on Linux/x86 and on FreeBSD/ia64). the Posix standard specifies symbolic [errno.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/errno.h.html) names.

I recommend you to read good books like [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com) and [Advanced Unix Programming](http://basepath.com/aup).

If you want to make portable code for Linux, Windows, MacOSX you could use frameworks like Qt

On my Debian/Linux/AMD64 system I have

```
#define EINPROGRESS 115 /* Operation now in progress */
```

in header `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h`

When using a [syscall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) such as [recv(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/recv.2.html), read its man page to understand when a particular error can occur in it.

NB: `GetLastError` is not a standard Linux function. It is specific to your program, or to some library linked to it.

Comment: the program runs under linux. The log display the error id is is 115. And I want to know what error can result this error code(115)?

Comment: As I commented, use `perror` inside the program, or `grep 115 /usr/include/*/errno.h`; but perhaps your software has its own application specific (not kernel related) error codes??

Answer (score 1):

You are running under Linux, so what it says in Windows `error.h` is completely and utterly irrelevant. In Linux's `errno.h,` 115 is:

```
#define EINPROGRESS 115 /* Operation now in progress */
```

> I think the error code in linux && windows must be the same as TCP error.

You have no basis for that belief.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I am wrong at it. Thank you. So could you please kindly tell me what result this error?

Comment: The `errno(3]` and `recv(2)` man pages will tell you: type `man errno` (or `man 3 errno`) and `man recv` (or `man 2 recv`).